# Combine two columns of data into one in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a solution to combine to columns of data into one in Excel. The data is not adjacent, so I wish to combine data in Column A with data in Column C, placing the results into Column E.

An example:

```
Row       A        B        C        D        E (Desired result)
1                                             1
2         1                 2                 2
3         3                 4                 3
4         5                 6                 4
5         1                 2                 5
6                                             6
7         7                 8                 7
8                                             8
```

It's important that the data is in order of first appearance by row. As an aside it would also be good to avoid duplicates (see the second 1 & 2 not duplicated in example col E), but that is easily dealt with afterwards.

I also need it to ignore blank cells.

Would prefer to achieve this via VBA.

Comment: Please, can you explain a bit better why your desired result is adding up each row from row 2 onwards instead of row 1? Would that be, because untill row two no values have been added to the 'array' of values?

Comment: It isn't. It is putting in the values of cells in this order: A2, C2, A3, C3, A4, C4, A5, C5, A7, C7...

Comment: @AndrewAbbott Why is row 1 in column E blank, why not start listing the values there?

Comment: No reason, I just started in the wrong place after editing my example. Amended it now.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the cells in columns A and C, if they don't already exist in Column E, list them sequentially:

```
Sub Test()

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("E:E"), Cells(i, 1).Value) = 0 Then
                Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 5).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
        End If

        If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("E:E"), Cells(i, 3).Value) = 0 Then
                Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 5).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

[image: img1]